# debugging python scripts using lldb

Tags: python, debugging, lldb

I am trying to debug python file using lldb, but I keep getting below error:

```
xxxxx: lldb python lldb-test-2.py
(lldb) target create "python"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xxxxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/Users/xxxxx/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Current executable set to 'python' (x86_64).
(lldb) settings set -- target.run-args  "lldb-test-2.py"
(lldb) r
Process 69299 launched: '/Users/xxxxx/anaconda2/envs/work-env-test/bin/python' (x86_64)
Process 69299 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_SOFTWARE (code=131072, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007fffa478cb1a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__posix_spawn + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__posix_spawn:
->  0x7fffa478cb1a <+10>: jae    0x7fffa478cb24            ; <+20>
    0x7fffa478cb1c <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fffa478cb1f <+15>: jmp    0x7fffa4785cd4            ; cerror
    0x7fffa478cb24 <+20>: retq   
Target 0: (python) stopped.
(lldb)
```

Here's my test code:

```
#!/Users/xxxxx/anaconda2/envs/work-env-test/bin/python
import os
import numpy as np

def printTest():
    print("This is a test")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printTest()
```

I am able to run this script normally on terminal but cant use lldb to run.

Comment: It looks like the attempt to launch a subprocess is being denied.  It's kind of odd that that would happen only in the debugger.  Can you see what is being spawned?  The stack above this exception might show you what is being done.  Also the second argument to posix_spawn is the path of the spawned binary so `print (char *) $arg2` should show this.

Comment: (lldb) print (char *) $arg2
(char *) $0 = 0x00007fffa471d46a "/bin/sh"

Comment: backtrace is pretty long, pasting in multiple comments:
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
frame #0: 0x00007fffa478cb1a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__posix_spawn + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fffa4787ed5 libsystem_kernel.dylib`posix_spawn + 386
    frame #2: 0x00007fffa4713e10 libsystem_c.dylib`system + 418
    frame #3: 0x0000000101b20469 multiarray.so`loadlib + 57
    frame #4: 0x0000000100019a1b dyld`ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 385
frame #5: 0x0000000100019c1e dyld`ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40

Comment: frame #6: 0x00000001000154aa dyld`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 338
    frame #7: 0x0000000100014524 dyld`ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 138
    frame #8: 0x00000001000145b9 dyld`ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 75

Comment: frame #8: 0x00000001000145b9 dyld`ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 75
    frame #9: 0x00000001000097cd dyld`dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 87
    frame #10: 0x00000001000113ec dyld`dlopen + 556
    frame #11: 0x00007fffa465b832 libdyld.dylib`dlopen + 59
    frame #12: 0x000000010017b0c8 libpython2.7.dylib`_PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc + 312

Comment: So it looks like multiarray.soloadlib is trying to spawn a shell.  Not sure why it would do that.  That isn't allowed, but maybe this error is handled - and turned into a posix_spawn error - when not running under the debugger, and that's why you only notice this in the debugger.  What happens if you just continue after hitting this EXC_SOFTWARE?

Comment: @JimIngham I cant continue as the python process stopped.
Target 0: (python) stopped.